# How to sum a values in an array using typescript

Tags: typescript

## I want to calculate the total value of the below array

```
 let Gender1 = [ Male1[22,34,76,24,30],
                    Male2[12,15,18,20],
                    Male3[16,18] ];
```

Comment: it's not a valid json object (really it's not valid anything)

Answer (score 1):

- firstly need to flat your array via `flat` method
- then via `reduce` method we can sum all number in the array

```js
let Gender1 = [[22,34,76,24,30], [12,15,18,20], [16,18]];

const result = Gender1.flat().reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix the formatting of your arrays, Use `.flatMap` and `.reduce` to flatten and then summarize.

```js
let gender1 = [[22,34,76,24,30], [12,15,18,20], [16,18]]
let sum = gender1.flatMap(num => num).reduce((a, b) => a+b)
```

This has nothing to do with Angular specifically.